# Connecting 2 Virtual Machines with OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am trying to connect two Windows Virtualbox virtual machines through OpenVPN. Both machines are Windows 10 machines, named VM-Client and VM-Server, but I want them to be in different networks.

Right now, I can connect OpenVPN on the VM-Server, but can't connect on VM-Client. I am getting a TLS error when trying to connect VM1-Client to VM-Server. I have opened port 1194 on both virtual machines and my host machine, which is Windows as well.

I also set up port forwarding on my router. I've researched this issue for two weeks, but I've been mostly getting VM guest to host VPN configuration solutions. I have tried different networking configurations in Virtualbox such as:

- VM-Client and VM-Server both having NAT connections
- VM-Client having a bridge connection and VM-Server having a NAT connection
- VM-Client and Server both having host-only and NAT connections
- Connecting both VMs to a NAT network

I also tried to route traffic from VM-Client to VM-Server by inputting a new route in VM-Client's route table, but I am pretty sure I did that wrong.

Does someone know how I can successfully set this connection up in Virtualbox and OpenVPN? All attempts to help with solutions with be appreciated.

Comment: In VMware I can make a custom NAT connection and give it a different subnet to the main NAT.  Can you do this in Virtual Box.  That should work if you can.

Comment: Yes. I can do this. However my issue is when doing this, how to get OpenVPN to connect.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options you can use to connect two VMs:

- Use the "Internal network" mode, specifying the same name for both VMs.
- Create a *custom* NAT network in VirtualBox's "Tools" section. While all VMs using the default NAT mode are isolated from each other, all VMs using the same custom NAT network will be connected.
- Attach both VMs to the same "Bridged" interface (this will of course also connect both of them to the same physical network).

> I want them to be in different networks

For that, you generally need a *router* to actually forward packets between the two networks.

The "router" could be a third VM running some OS capable of routing (e.g. Linux), or it could be the host OS (with VMs talking to it via "Host-only" interfaces). The routing tables of both the VM1-Client *and* VM3-Server would need to reference VM2-Router as the gateway.

```
VM1-Client <==[internal network A]==> VM2-Router <==[internal network 2]==> VM3-Server
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try these instructions out and let you know the results.

Comment: Thanks again. Do you know once I connect VMs, how to successfully connect OpenVPN between the machines?

Comment: Investigate why it *doesn't* successfully connect.